# Redirecting a URL that contains a specific part to another URL using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like to know if there is a way to redirect a URL that looks like this:

```
https://www.example.com/p=d3d82c7c
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/polls/poll?poll=d3d82c7c
```

using htaccess.

What I want to do is to create a more simple link for the users. Is that possible with htaccess only?

PS: the code at the end may change within each URL.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Usually its advised to have user friendly URLs in your case `https://www.example.com/p=d3d82c7c` and from backend it could be served by `https://www.example.com/polls/poll?poll=d3d82c7c`. Could you please confirm if you want to change URL in browser also(redirect)? Though your question says that but as per thumb rule only user friendly URLs should be visible on browser hence confirming with you here.

Comment: thank you very much! no there is no need to change it in the browser. the link could change then to the "long" one when already redirected, otherwise i may have some problems with all references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^.*=(.*) polls/poll?poll=$1 [L]
```

OR with your shown samples if your URI always starts with `p` then you could try following, but make sure either previous OR this only one of them should be used at a time.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^p.*=(.*) polls/poll?poll=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I think the OP  wants an external URL redirection.

Comment: @AmitVerma, yeah I thought that too but considering the rule of front end URL should be user friendly and backend url should be real one, I went with this approach. Let me confirm once with OP in comments, cheers.

Comment: sorry for bothering, for some reason the link remains the same and does not change in the browser in both solutions. the page itself works as long as I don't click any where, otherwise it redirects me to 404.

Comment: @ntsu, could you please give a sample(not real near to it with test values) of your URL which you are hitting here? Because for your given sample url it worked fine for me, when I tested it.

Comment: if i hit /p=e5eb1c40 i get to the right page, but when i click somewhere (form action) it goes to a blank page which is lets say /entry.new.php — which is wrong because this must be /polls/entry.new.php, should i change that everywhere in my code or is there is another simple way? thank you.

Comment: @ntsu, So when I check on url `http://localhost/p=d3d82c7c` it rewrites it to(in backend) `http://localhost/polls/poll?poll=d3d82c7c` like shown sample, not sure for other URLs what conditions you have to rewrite them, My first rule(before OR) is generic one it will NOT check which url is being hit and will simply rewrite it to `polls/poll?poll=captured value after = in actual requested url`. Let me know if we are on same page, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I got it right now. I needed to change Base URL in the code, this works best. thank you very much and have a nice day!

Comment: @ntsu, your welcome, good to know it got fixed. So is it you added `RewriteBase` in .htaccess file? Just for learning I am asking :)

Comment: yes of course I did!, won't work otherwise ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
Redirect 301 /en/php/project.html http://www.example.org/newpage.html
```